# Can it be done with one query? MySQL only one table

Tags: mysql

I can't cope with writing the right query (mysql). I would like to do this with query instead of procedure. Unless it's impossible to do.

The input is: pozycja_id=315
[image]

Now I have to sum up all the values with correction
[image]

Please give me some tips on how to go about it.
Thank you all

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. And show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: The top one is a tree traversal or hierarchical query. You can already find dolutions to that one here on SO. The bottom one seems to be a self join.

Comment: *Can it be done with one query?* On version 8+ - easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Shadow, this is my solution in 2 query ( mysql < 8 )

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT magazyn_id SEPARATOR ',') 
 FROM (SELECT * FROM rs_magazyn ORDER BY korekta_pozycji_id  DESC,pozycja_id DESC) products_sorted, 
 (select @pv := '305') initialisation 
 WHERE find_in_set(pozycja_id, @pv) and length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', korekta_pozycji_id))`

 SELECT SUM(T2.qty_out+IFNULL((SELECT SUM(qty_out) suma FROM rs_magazyn 
 WHERE korekta_pozycji_id=T2.pozycja_id),0)) suma 
 FROM rs_magazyn AS T1 LEFT JOIN rs_magazyn AS T2 ON T1.magazyn_id=T2.do_magazyn_id
 WHERE T1.magazyn_id IN (5,16 {GROUP_CONCAT FROM FIRST QUERY})`
```